# Understanding Typescript definition

Tags: typescript, d3.js

From the `@types/d3` definition, we have the lines:

```
export type ValueFn<T extends BaseType, Datum, Result> = (this: T, datum: Datum, index: number, groups: T[] | ArrayLike<T>) => Result;

attrTween(name: string): ValueFn<GElement, Datum, (t: number) => string> | undefined;
```

When I use the function `attrTween`, I use it like so :

```
caller.attrTween("points", (d, index, groups) => { return (t) => {return "";};  }
```

In which caller is `Transition<BaseType, PieArcDatum<number>`

These parameters are inferred by VSCode as :

```
(parameter) d: d3.PieArcDatum<number>
(parameter) index: number
(parameter) groups: d3.BaseType[] | d3.ArrayLike<d3.BaseType>
```

How does type definition enforce this behaviour?
Can It be explained *word-by-word*, especially the ***Generic*** usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`attrTween` has [three separate overloads](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/84a9f0a15d5e765e20fef3a04b43824c9d3370e1/types/d3-transition/index.d.ts#L203-L228), where the third entry (and only two-argument overload with a non-null second argument) is:

```
/**
 * Assign the attribute tween for the attribute with the specified name to the specified interpolator factory.
 * An interpolator factory is a function that returns an interpolator; when the transition starts, the factory is evaluated for each selected element.
 * The returned interpolator will then be invoked for each frame of the transition, in order,
 * being passed the eased time t, typically in the range [0, 1]. Lastly, the return value of the interpolator will be used to set the attribute value.
 * The interpolator must return a string.
 *
 * @param name Name of attribute.
 * @param factory An interpolator factory which is evaluated for each selected element, in order, being passed the current datum (d),
 * the current index (i), and the current group (nodes), with this as the current DOM element (nodes[i]). The interpolator factory returns a string interpolator,
 * which takes as its argument eased time t, typically in the range [0, 1] and returns the interpolated string.
 */
attrTween(name: string, factory: ValueFn<GElement, Datum, (t: number) => string>): this;
```

This matches your call much better than the overload you listed. This definition exists in Transition, which is defined as the following:

```
export interface Transition<GElement extends BaseType, Datum, PElement extends BaseType, PDatum>
```

With this, we can see the direct mapping:

- `d` is `Datum`, which from `caller` is `d3.PieArcDatum<number>`
- `index` is `number`
- `groups` is `T[] | ArrayLike<T>` where `T extends BaseType`.

  - Per `attrTween`'s definition, `T` in `ValueFn` is the same as `GElement` in `Transition`.
  - `GElement` is `BaseType` per your `callee`.
  - Therefore `T` is `BaseType`, so `groups` is `d3.BaseType[] | d3.ArrayLike<d3.BaseType>` as you see it.